# How to optimize a nested for loop that uses `re.finditer`?

Tags: python, optimization

I currently have a task of annotating substrings with labels in Python and am using Python's RegEx library to do that. I'll give an example of what I mean since it's hard to explain coherently:

```
label_dictionary = {'coca cola': 'company', 'united states': 'country'}
text = "Coca Cola is a company that has its headquarters in the United States."
 
for text in texts: # There are multiple strings.
    labels = ['O'] * len(text)

    for entity, label in label_dictionary.items():
        spans = [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in re.finditer(entity, text)]

        for span in spans:
            start, end = span

            labels[start] = label
            labels = labels[:start + 1] + ([label] * (end - start - 1)) + labels[end:]
```

Those of you who are familiar with natural language processing may have figured it out, but I'm trying to create a dataset for named entity recognition.

I want to get the start and end spans of each entity from the `label_dictionary` then mark those positions in the text with a label.

I'm wondering if I could use less for loops since that's where my code is taking so long, but am not sure if there's even a viable way to do this.

Any tips appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in your code example. We want to be able to copy and paste the code for testing purposes. See [mre]. Also, please remember that this is **not a discussion forum**. We want clear, specific, **directly asked**, questions, [not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) "Any tips appreciated" or your [thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160).

Comment: You are collecting up spans then immediately going through them - this is an unnecessary extra step.

Comment: @MattClarke Could you elaborate a little bit more please? Are you implying that it may be better to save the collected spans, then iterate through the saved spans later?

Comment: No, you are iterating through the matches and collecting the start and ends then iterating through the spans. You could do this in one which would remove a loop. `for span in spans:` becomes `for match in re.finditer(entity, text):` and `start, end = span` becomes `start, end = match.start(), match.end()` then the `spans = [...]` line can be deleted.

Comment: @MattClarke Thanks for pointing that out. Your suggestion shortened my total time from 10 hours to 7, so now I guess I need to start looking for other ways to shorten that if it's possible.

Comment: From the example above, it looks like a candidate for multiprocessing, see  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of entities in your `label_dictionary`, looping over all of them would get quite expensive. For example, if you have 10000 entities, you would search every text 10000 times for a substring.
Your can optimize this, by searching for all entities simultaneously using regular expressions.

For example, the regular expression `Coca\ Cola|United\ States` searches for both "Coca Cola" and "United States".

The following example combines all entities into one regular expression and prints the information you seem to need:

```py
import re

label_dictionary = {'Coca Cola': 'company', 'United States': 'country'}
text = "Coca Cola is a company that has its headquarters in the United States."


regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(entity) for entity in label_dictionary))

for m in re.finditer(regex, text):
    print('Span:', m.span())
    entity = m.group()
    print('Entity:', entity)
    print('Label:', label_dictionary[entity])
```

PS: It's a good idea to use `re.escape` because your entities might contain characters with a special meaning in regular expression (think e.g. of `A* Company`).